# Lambda function to filter AWS EC2 instances based on tags?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a Lambda function that will filter through all running instances, finding the instances that have certain tags, and then shut those instances down. I am relatively new to using AWS Lambda, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is what I have so far, I am currently just trying to get the filter to work as I already know how to shut down the instances in Lambda. I am getting an error that says "module initialization error" currently. Any advice?

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    filters = [{
         'Name': 'tag:Application',
         'Values': ['exampleName']
       },
       {
        'Name': 'tag:Vertical',
        'Values': ['exampleVertical']
     }]

    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=filters)

    RunningInstances = [instance.id for instance in instances]

    if len(RunningInstances) > 0:
       print("found instances with tag")
    else:
        print("none found")
```

UPDATE: This code works and can find the instances, the problem was caused because the proper roles were not assigned to the function originally.

Comment: where are you mentioning your access credentials , I mean in the lambda env variables ?

Comment: did you create a lambda function from console or uploaded a zip ?

Comment: I wasn't mentioning any access credentials..where would I put those? And I wrote it in Microsoft Visual Code and then pasted my code into the inline code editor from the Lambda page..probably not a good way to do it? @tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic working snippet of `stopping` a `running` instances for given tags -

```
from boto3.session import Session
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

aws_access_key = ''
aws_secret_key = ''
region = ''

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   try:
       sess = Session(aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key,
                   aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_key)
       ec2_conn = sess.client(service_name='ec2', region_name=region)

       instance_ids = []
       reservations = ec2_conn.describe_instances(
                                Filters=[
                                    {
                                        'Name': 'tag:Application',
                                        'Values': [
                                            'exampleName',
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        'Name': 'tag:Vertical',
                                        'Values': [
                                            'exampleVertical',
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        'Name': 'instance-state-name',
                                        'Values': [
                                            'running',
                                        ]
                                    },
                                ])['Reservations']

      for reservation in reservations:
          instances = reservation['Instances']
          for instance in instances:
              instance_ids.append(instance['InstanceId'])

      print("Stopping instances: {}".format(','.join(instance_ids)))

      stopped_instances_response = ec2_conn.stop_instances(
                             InstanceIds=instance_ids)

      print(stopped_instances_response)
  except ClientError as e:
     print(e)
```

P.S: You can add credentials from environment variables also.

Comment: Thank you @Tom ! After looking further into my issue, I realized that the problem caused because I did not assign the proper role to the Lambda function. Once I assigned the correct role, my original code worked. Thanks for your quick response and help!